# beaglebone black doesn't autoboot when powered over jack or vdd pins

Tags: power-supply, power, linux, beaglebone-black, beagleboard

I have a BBB and it works quite well however when I power it over the Barrel connector or over the vdd pins rather then use the usb connection it doesn't automatically boot. When I put the barrel connector and usb in at the same time and then remove the usb it continues running. This is running on ubuntu arm. I have tested that the power supply is between 4.95 and 5.04 V and is capable of sustaining this to just over 1 Ampere

Edit 
it appear the BBB does boot when supplied with 4.7 V lab power supply at ~0.4A power consumption. So that suggest something is wrong with the power supply. But how do I test it seeing I was able to verify that it can supply 1A at 5V.

This power supply works by feeding a 12V battery into a [step down](http://www.produktinfo.conrad.com/datenblaetter/150000-174999/167833-da-01-en-STEP_DOWN_KONVERTER_1A_W78_ADJ.pdf) to convert it down to 5V if that matters.

Comment: Are you able to read the serial port on boot? Anyway, try using different power supply.

Comment: You mean over usb? That seems to work normally (I can ssh onto the board over usb if that is what you mean). And what problem do you think this power supply has? The BBB normally only puls around 0.4 A

Comment: BBB doesn't have serial over USB. I mean connect to the UART pins and read the u-boot messages.

Comment: Any idea hot to best listen to the UART pins using a laptop a bit of wire and some servo's?

Comment: No way :) You need some TTL to RS-232 level shifter along with serial port on your computer, or USB to TTL serial converter. Maybe if you have some Arduino junk around, you could make some low-end converter ...

Comment: I have added some extra information about the power supply by the way any way that might help?

Comment: Check the ripple of you step-down converter.

Comment: According to the datasheet (now added to question) it should be 7 to 45 mvpp at 1000mA, that shouldn't be a problem?

Comment: Ok, it might be obvious.. but is it right polarity? Do you have any LEDs lit?

Comment: Polarity appears correct, if I disconnect the usb from the BBB then it continues to run it's only auto booting that does not work (so it continues to run if already booted).

Comment: What happens if you connect and then push reset button?

Comment: The beaglebone doesn't fully reboot instead the power led remains lit but the rest doesn't light, normally the power led remains dark when powered over the  barrel connected but not booted.

Comment: I think you should find a stock BBB power supply, or similar. It appears that you have some issues with your setup.

Comment: The problem is that I'm working on a robot so a "stock power supply" isn't likely to work as I cannot have a long cable running to the BBB, it has to be powered over battery.

Comment: Still you can use it to test the board.

Comment: I can look for it but I did just boot it over a lab power supply generating 5V and 0.3A so that does work

Comment: So again. Yuor power supply setup is obviously not good enough. Maybe the startup current, maybe the ripple, maybe something else.

Comment: I have tried adding a capacitor but that didn't work, any other idea how to reduce rilpe/start-up current?

Comment: Did you tie the battery and the related 5v grounds together?

Comment: the ground of the battery is connected to the ground of the step down and the ground of the 5V is connected to the ground of the step down